# В консоле VS С# после выполнения оперции в конце вылазит всегда текст

Tags: c#

В консоли нарисовал звездочку, затем нажал Enter, а далее следом вот этот текст:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 13476) exited with code 0. To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops. Press any key to close this window

Как сделать чтобы он больше не появлялся? Среда разработки VS 2019

Comment: Ну, он вам ясным английским языком пишет: `To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.`. Когда компилируете в релизе - этой надписи не будет, но в дебаге лучше оставлять эту надпись, мало ли что.

Comment: Cпасибо. Просто глаза мозолит в конце, первый раз запустил VS19, до этого был VS13